# Mysql grabbing correct price depending on date

Tags: mysql

I have a table that looks like the following:

[image]

The query below obviously returns all records in the table

```
SELECT * FROM pricing
```

My problem I have is that I want to display the correct price based on todays date. I know I can grab todays date using CURDATE() but how do I grab the row that shows the price of 70.00 as this is the correct price until today is equal to or greater than 2017-02-01?

Thanks in advance.

John

Comment: `SELECT * FROM pricing WHERE start_date>=CURRDATE() ORDER BY start_date ASC LIMIT 1`

Answer (score 1):

`select price from table where product = YourProduct and date <= YourDate order by date desc limit 1`

Comment: thanks. That would work if there was only one product in the table (I should have included more in the table example!). Unfortunately this will not work with multiple products.

Comment: Trouble is I need the current price for all products so there will be multiple rows - I am struggling with this one, thought it would be easy!